# Vue.js: mutation for deleting a comment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, action, mutation

I have been working on the feature of comment deleting and came across a question regarding a mutation for an action.
Here is my client:

```
delete_post_comment({post_id, comment_id} = {}) {
// DELETE /api/posts/:post_id/comments/:id
return this._delete_request({
  path: document.apiBasicUrl + '/posts/' + post_id + '/comments/' + comment_id,
 });
}
```

Here is my store:

```
import Client from '../client/client';
import ClientAlert from '../client/client_alert';
import S_Helper from '../helpers/store_helper';

const state = {
 comment: {
  id: 0,
  body: '',
  deleted: false,
 },
 comments: [],
};

const actions = {
 deletePostComment({ params }) {
 // DELETE /api/posts/:post_id/comments/:id
 document.client
  .delete_post_comment({ params })
  .then(ca => {
    S_Helper.cmt_data(ca, 'delete_comment', this);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    ClientAlert.std_fail_with_err(error);
  });
 },
};

 delete_comment(context, id) {
 context.comment = comment.map(comment => {
   if (!!comment.id && comment.id === id) {
     comment.deleted = true;
     comment.body = '';
    }
  });
 },
};

export default {
 state,
 actions,
 mutations,
 getters,
};
```

I am not quite sure if I wrote my mutation correctly. So far, when I am calling the action via `on-click` inside the component, nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing you are using vuex the flow should be:

[image]

according to this flow, on the component template

```
@click="buttonAction(someParams)"
```

vm instance, methods object:

```
buttonAction(someParams) {
    this.$store.dispatch('triggerActionMethod', { 'something_else': someParams })
}
```

vuex **actions** - Use actions for the logic, ajax call ecc.

```
triggerActionMethod: ({commit}, params) => {
    commit('SOME_TRANSATION_NAME', params)
}
```

vuex **mutations** - Use mutation to make the changes into your state

```
'SOME_TRANSATION_NAME' (state, data) { state.SOME_ARG = data }
```

Comment: But don't we need to add `comment.deleted = true; comment.body = ' '` inside the mutation?

Comment: Also thank you for clearing how to dispatch the action correctly using vuex.

Comment: Yes, use always a mutation to make the change. Use actions for the logic